# websocket: bad handshake (HTTP status 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable) - Go-Ethereum

Tags: go, solidity, polygon, go-ethereum

I have encountered a problem. I have followed this tutorial (https://goethereumbook.org/en/event-subscribe/) in goethereum, but when I replace node endpoint matic(wss://rpc-mumbai.matic.today), I encounter this problem.

ERROR: websocket: bad handshake (HTTP status 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable)

My contract is on Mumbai matic network, this address is 0x6d66A45b628A7B497B618FA637F77a47Ab1E8943

Thank you for your help

Comment: *"503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"* looks like a server side issue